# split string using awk returning blank

Tags: bash, shell, awk, split

I'm trying the following based on code samples I found:

```
echo "file.txt" | awk '{split($0,a,"."); print a[0]}'
```

But it's returning a blank output.

Any hint?

Answer (score 6):

You code is correct however the array `a` starts from 1 with the `split` function:

```
$ echo "file.txt" | awk '{split($0,a,"."); print a[0]}'

$ echo "file.txt" | awk '{split($0,a,"."); print a[1]}'
file

$ echo "file.txt" | awk '{split($0,a,"."); print a[2]}'
txt
```

From the `gawk` manual:

> split(string, array [, fieldsep [, seps ] ])
>
> Divide string into pieces separated by fieldsep and store the pieces
>   in array and the separator strings in the seps array. The first piece
>   is stored in array[1], the second piece in array[2], and so forth.

Comment: you're impossible to beat! You must be hitting refresh with a frequency of 2Hz or something :-)

Comment: Thank you! didn't know about the index starting from 1.
@FredrikPihl lol :P

Comment: No problem, it's one of those mistake we all make. @FredrikPihl I have the fastest gun in the west!

Comment: @FredrikPihl writing a small script to check certain tags is not hard thing. when you are in break, take a look that list generated by the script, you will be the fastest! well, `F5` is another way to do, I don't believe that sudo_O keeps pressing `F5` though.. ^_^

Comment: I just have `awk` set as a favorite tag so the question show up in yellow/gold *(no F5, no script needed)*. `awk` isn't so popular. Try answering question in `python`, `C#`, `<insert more popular tags>`...

Comment: @kent - I'm just saying that between you, sudo_O, sputnick and some more, it's very hard to post something; you only have seconds before any of you post something. 4 upvotes for this answer is cheap :-)

Comment: @FredrikPihl yes competition is good though! Voting is completely arbitrary, I don't thing 4 is cheap, [see this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096490/print-second-last-column-field-in-awk).

Comment: @sudo_O thx for the link. he used `print` as a function. `print(...)` that's why he got 44 up. you only got 4 (so far) because you didn't write  `print (a[0])` :D

Comment: FWIW I'd take a point off if he DID use `print(a[0])`* :-). *print is not a function it's a buitin so using `print(foo)` is not calling a function `print()` with argument `foo`, it's calling a builtin `print` with argument `(foo)`.

Comment: I'm actually surprised that the posted solution worked since the 3rd argument to split() is an RE, not a string, and "." is the RE metacharacter for "any character" so I'd have expected the string to get split into an array of N null strings where N is the number of characters in the original string plus 1. Have to think about that for a bit to figure out why it worked as it obviously does. I'd have thought you'd need /[.]/ or similar.

Comment: @sudo_O Whether it's a regexp constant `/foo/` or a dynamic regexp `"foo"` or `x="foo"; ... ~ x`, it's still a regexp, only escape sequences should change between the 2 forms. I don't know why "." is working in this example.

Comment: Clearer definition further down `"Modern implementations of awk, including gawk, allow the third argument to be a regexp constant (/abc/) as well as a string. (d.c.) The POSIX standard allows this as well"`

Comment: @sudo_O - again that doesn't matter, they're both regexps. I just figured it out though - it's because split() does field-splitting and there's a feature of field splitting that treats single characters uniquely in that it ignores their RE metacharacter functionality. `"FS == any other single character
    Fields are separated by each occurrence of the character. Multiple successive occurrences delimit empty fields, as do leading and trailing occurrences. The character can even be a regexp metacharacter; it does not need to be escaped.`

Comment: @sudo_O Me too and I have a sneaking suspicion there's now things I'm learning then forgetting and then having to learn all over again!

Comment: @EdMorton I submitted a bug email to bug-gawk regarding the split() last evening. you should have already seen it in that mailing list.

Comment: @Kent It's not a bug, it's a documented feature of field-splitting. split($0,a,".") behaves the same way that FS="." does. Now I wonder how to use a single char as it's RE metacharacter for FS though - I mean how do I get field-splitting with `FS=.` like I would with `split($0,a,/./)` rather than `split($0,a,".")`? I actually don't think it's possible. BTW I'm not on that mailing list.

Answer (score 5):

try

```
echo "file.txt" | awk '{split($0,a,"."); print a[1]}'
```

awk array index is **1-based**.

Comment: Thank you! didn't know about the index starting from 1.