# How to cut column data from flat file

Tags: linux, shell, text, awk, sed

I've data in format below;

```
111,Ja,M,Oes,2012-08-03 16:42:00,x,xz
112,Ln,d,D,Gn,2012-08-03 16:51:00,y,yx
```

I need to create files with data in the sequence below:

```
111,x,xz
112,y,yz
```

In output format, we've first value before comma and last two comma prefix values. Here we can have any number of commas in-between.

Kindly advise, how can generate required output file from input file in Linux machine.

Comment: Can the number of commas in a row differ from row to row?

Comment: I tried to upload data in SQL Server ; then relalized that there are multiple commas which was breaking csv upload.

Comment: @fancyPants yes; number of commas in a row differ from row to row. we need first and last two values only in each row.

Comment: Try with: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096490/print-second-last-column-field-in-awk?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Awk` statement for this is pretty straight-forward. Set the input and output field separators and print the fields using `$1`..`$NF`, where `$NF` is the value of the last column,

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{print $1,$(NF-1),$NF}' input.csv > newfile.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

Not much to this one in awk:

```
awk -F"," 'BEGIN{OFS=","}{print $1,$(NF-1), $NF}' inFile > outFile
```

We split the lines in awk with a comma `-F","` and then print the first field `$1`, the second to last field `$(NF-1)`, and the last field `$NF`.

`NF` is the "Number of fields" so subtracting 1 from it will give you the second to last item.

Answer (score 1):

with `sed`

```
$ sed -r 's/([^,]+).*(,[^,]+,[^,]+)/\1\2/' file
111,x,xz
112,y,yx
```

or

```
$ sed -r 's/([^,]+).*((,[^,]+){2})/\1\2/' file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{print substr($1,1,4) substr($2,10,4)}' file

111,x,xz
112,y,yx
```