# AWK - Reverse field order

Tags: awk

How can I print the second Field, counting from the end of the fields, dynamically?

input

> 4 6 5 **6** 4
>
> 4 **5** 6
>
> 7 8 9 **6** 3
>
> 4 **5** 6

I would like to print the second column, numbered from the last record (dynamically)

The desired result is:

```
6
5
6
5
```

I tried `-$2` that does not work.

Comment: See: [Print second last column/field in awk](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2096490/3776858)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Print second last column/field in awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096490/print-second-last-column-field-in-awk)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples.

```
awk '{print $(NF-1)}' Input_file
```

Where `NF` is out of the box(default) variable of `awk` and represents the total number of fields in a line. So what I have done is after `$` I have put `NF-1` means telling to print 2nd last field here.